# Elasticsearch aggregate on URL hostname

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I am indexing documents with a field containing a url:

```
[
    'myUrlField' => 'http://google.com/foo/bar'
]
```

Now what I´d like to get out of elasticsearch is an aggregation on the url field.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myIndex/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "facets": {
    "groupByMyUrlField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myUrlField"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This is all well and good, but the default analyzer tokenizes the field so that each part of the url is a token, so I get hits for `http`, `google.com`, `foo` and `bar`. But basically I am only interested in the hostname of the url, the `google.com`.

Can I use facets to group by a specific token?

```
"field": "myUrlField.0"
```

or something like that?

Querying for the "not_analyzed" index is also no good because I want to group by hostname, and not by unique urls.

Would love to be able to do this in elasticsearch and not in my client code.
Thanks

Comment: perhaps you need something like pattern tokenizer for that field? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to aggregate urls by domains:

First you tokenize the full url as a single token using a [keyword tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) (which works the same as `not_analyzed` [under the hood](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html)), then you extract the domain with a regex, using a [pattern capture token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html). Finally we discard the original full url token thanks to `preserve_original` option.

Which leads to:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "capture_domain_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": false,
          "flags": "CASE_INSENSITIVE",
          "patterns": [
            "https?:\/\/([^/]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "domain_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "capture_domain_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "weblink": {
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "domain_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We check how our urls are tokenized:

```
curl -sXGET http://localhost:9200/url_analyzer/_analyze\?analyzer\=domain_analyzer\&pretty -d 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia' | grep token
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "en.wikipedia.org",
```

This looks good, now let's aggregate our urls by domains using [latest aggregations features](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) (which will deprecate facets in near future).

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/url_analyzer/_search?pretty" -d'
{
  "aggregations": {
    "tokens": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "url"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Output:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "tokens" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "en.wikipedia.org",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "www.elasticsearch.org",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
```

From here you can go further and apply an additional [shingle token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) on top of this to match queries such as "en.wikipedia", "wikipedia.org", if you want to avoid exact matches while searching for a domain.

Comment: Thanks, whats the advantage of your approach of using a filter over setting up a custom tokenizer?