# ElasticSearch - indexing URLs and aggregating on Domains

Tags: elasticsearch

Similar to this question [Elasticsearch aggregate on URL hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867657/elasticsearch-aggregate-on-url-hostname)

I'm wanting to store URLs and be able to aggregate on Domains

Using ES6 I have the following mapping defined

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "url_domains": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original" : false,
          "patterns": [
            "https?:\/\/([^/]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "url": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "url_domains",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        },
        "full_url": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "stop"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "urls": {
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata" : true,
          "fields": {
            "domain": {
              "type": "text",
              "fielddata" : true,
              "analyzer": "url"
            },
            "full": { 
              "type":  "text",
              "fielddata" : true,
              "analyzer": "full_url"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then load in the following data

```
POST /test/urls/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"url": "http://gmail1.com/hello/world"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"url": "https://gmail2.com/hello"}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"url": "http://gmail3.com/"}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}
{"url": "https://gmail4.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"5"}}
{"url": "https://www.gmail5.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"6"}}
{"url": "www.gmail6.coom"}
{"index":{"_id":"7"}}
{"url": "www.gmail7.co.uk/hello"}
```

When I do the following query

```
GET /test/urls/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "by_domain": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "url.domain",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following aggregations are returned:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "by_domain": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "coom",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "gmail1.com",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "gmail2.com",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "gmail3.com",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "gmail4.com",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "www.gmail5.com",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "www.gmail6",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "www.gmail7.co.uk/hello",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

From running the Analyzer I can see that documents 6 and 7 are not treated as URL's, but are of type ALPHANUM.

How can I get the domains of documents 6 and 7 correctly extracted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of persistence paid off ! Changed the pattern to this:

```
       "patterns": [
            "https?:\/\/([^/]+)",
            "(www[^/]+)"
          ]
```